# Cómo acomodar las imágenes que muestro de la base de datos?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, base-de-datos

mi problema es el siguiente...
Quiero mostrar las imágenes de mi DB en un página, mi idea era mostrarlas de 3 en 3 pero al ir insertando imágenes solo la primera linea me sale de 3 la segunda me muestra una y la tercera fila me muestra las 3
[image: Aquí como se muestra]

[image: Aquí]

Este es el código para mostrar las imagenes

```html
 <?php
 include('conexion.php');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM imagenes";
 $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
   ?>
      <div class="imagenes">
<?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<ul class="productos">
<li><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></b> </br>
         <img height="200px" width="300px" src="./<?php echo $row['ruta_imagen']; ?>">
            <p><?php echo$row['descripcion'];?></p></li></ul>
            <?php
    }
 ?>
</div>
```

Estos son los estilos

```css
.imagenes{
 overflow:hidden;
 width:80%;
 height:100%;
}
 .imagenes ul.productos li{
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  padding:30px;
  height:100%;
 list-style:none;
 overflow:hidden;
}

ul.productos li img{
display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
 text-decoration:none;

}
```

Si me pueden ayudar para que se puedan mostrar correctamente las imágenes por favor

Comment: Intenta sacar el `ul` fuera del `while`

Comment: Quieres decir que coloque el while despues del ul?

Comment: Si.............

Comment: no funciona compa solo se colocan de dos y eso que solo algunas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, todo funciona muy bien con tu codigo PHP, Pero tienes varios errores. En tu while has dejado dentro el UL y debes dejarlo fuera. Tambien debes de usar CSS ya que es cuestion de estilos.
La razón por la que te sucede esto, es porque hay productos con textos mas largos 
que otros e imagenes con tamaños diferentes entonces tu siguiente columna se ajusta en donde existe una columna menos larga por eso vez que en tu segunda fila solo se muestra 1

```
ul.productos li {
  display: inline-block;   
  width: 32%;
}
.caption-img-product{
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 background-size:cover;
}
<ul class="productos">
 <li>Prueba 1</li>
 <li>Prueba 2</li>
 <li>Prueba 3</li>
 <li>Prueba 4</li>
 <li>Prueba 5</li>
```

```
 <?php
  include('conexion.php');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM imagenes";
  $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
 ?>
 <div class="imagenes">         
  <ul class="productos">
    <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
     <li>
      <?php echo $row['nombre'];?>
        <div class="caption-img-product" style="background-image:url('./<?php echo $row['ruta_imagen']; ?>');" ></div>
          <p><?php echo$row['descripcion'];?></p>
      </li>
     <?php
       }
     ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: oo ya veo, y sabes como hacer para que eso no suceda??? ya coloque el while fuera del <li> pero ahora solo me aparecen en forma de lista a pesar de los estlos

Comment: Si correcto ahora que ya tienes la lista, debes de usar
ul.productos li {
  display: inline-block;   
  width: 32%;
}
Esto alineara tu lista horizontalmente

Comment: Gracias bro, tenias razón con lo de los tamaños. Ya se acomodaron como quería, aunque no quedaron alineadas. Eso ya seria que las imágenes fueran todas del mismo tamaño, verdad?

Comment: Si correcto, lo que te recomiendo en este caso es usar las imagenes como background-image. te lo dejare en el codigo anterior. No olvides una manita arriba por la solución :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, le doy a la flechita arriba pero luego se quita, así que le di en la palomita xD. Gracias, por cierto,¿ en tu código?

Comment: Disculpa, pero no se visualizan las imagens, creo que la dirección no la reconoce o no se que pero lo muestra el texti

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con css.  Algo asi:

```css
ul.productos li {
  display: inline-block;   
  width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="productos">
<li>Prueba 1</li>
<li>Prueba 2</li>
<li>Prueba 3</li>
<li>Prueba 4</li>
<li>Prueba 5</li>
</ul>
```

Tambien te recomiendo que chequees `Bootstrap`

Comment: Si fueran imagenes ya insertadas si funciona pero como se van agregando deberian de acomodarse segun los estilos de css

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, intentalo asi.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar tu codigo php/html por esto

```
<?php
    include('conexion.php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM imagenes";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
?>
<div class="imagenes">
    <ul class="productos">
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
            <li class="imagenes">
                <?php echo $row['nombre'];?> </br>
                <img height="200px" width="300px" src="./<?php echo $row['ruta_imagen']; ?>">
                <p><?php echo$row['descripcion'];?></p>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

y tus estilos por esto:

CSS

```
.imagenes{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center
}
 .imagenes ul.productos li{
     width:30%;
     padding:30px;
     height:100%;
     list-style:none;
     overflow:hidden;
     text-align:left;
}

ul.productos li img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: gracias, pero me muestra las imagenes en en cascada :(